# Redirecting another domain to a current domain assigned to a Wordpress website

Tags: redirection, wordpress, htaccess

I have two domains `example.com` and `example.org` which are both registered through 1&1. The current Wordpress website uses the `.org` and the `.com` domain has been set to be redirected to `.org` from the 1&1 configuration panel.

However the redirection only works for the main page and not the subpages, so for example it is expected that `example.com/contact` redirects to `example.org/contact`, but instead it will be only redirected to `example.org`.

What I have already tried is modifying the `.htaccess` file, but I couldn't reach my goal.

```
RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org [R=301,L]
```

How can I redirect the `.com` to `.org` with the subpages being kept in the URL and not only getting redirected to main page?

Answer (score 0):

For you to keep the sub-pages intact when doing a URL redirect i.e. example.com/contact to example.org/contact, you would have to write use a ReWrite URL that would change the URL String and then redirect you the correct page.

If you have a lot of pages, this will a problem, but a few pages shouldn't be difficult.

Kind Regards,
Mo

Comment: This GitHub page should give you a good idea of the redirect rules: https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489